# Объясните, пожалуйста, часть кода на С++ (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt

Пытался разобраться как добавить чекбоксы на представление. Нашел один вариант: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786086/how-set-qcheckbox-in-qabstractitemmodel?newreg=95665e92ea474b6aab9fdb8e6ed244a5)
Так приведен такой вариант решения

```
QVector<int> status;
int SData::getStatus(int pos)
{
    return status.at(pos);
}

void SData::setStatus(int pos,int value)
{
    status.insert(pos, value);
}
QVariant STableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
        return rowList[index.row()][index.column()];
    else if (role == Qt::CheckStateRole && index.column() == 0)
    {

        int status = SData::instance().getStatus(index.row());
        if (status)
            return Qt::Checked;
        else
            return Qt::Unchecked;
    }
    else
        return QVariant();
}

bool STableModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index,
                         const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if (!index.isValid() /*|| role != Qt::EditRole*/)
        return false;
    if (role == Qt::CheckStateRole)
    {
        if ((Qt::CheckState)value.toInt() == Qt::Checked)
        {
            SData::instance().setStatus(index.row(),1);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            SData::instance().setStatus(index.row(), 0);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Непонятна эта часть кода:

```
int SData::getStatus(int pos)
{
    return status.at(pos);
}

void SData::setStatus(int pos,int value)
{
    status.insert(pos, value);
}
```

SData это класс наследованный от чего?  getStatus и setStatus это статические методы класса?

И больше всего непонятна конструкция:
 int status = SData::instance().getStatus(index.row());
instance() ? Это что? Как им пользоваться? Это метод наследного класса? Если да, то какого?

Comment: [тыц](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html)

Comment: Да с докоментацией все понятно. Вот только там нет: SData::instance().getStatus(index.row()); Что такое instance() ?

Comment: @wazza, can you help suggest what is instance() in constraction int status = SData::instance().getStatus(index.row());

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, удалось, разобраться. instance() оказался реализацией Singleton- заключается в использовании локальной статической переменной метода instance, хранящей единственный экземпляр класса (Синглтон Меерса).Блягодаря этой [статье](https://pro-prof.com/archives/1546)
На данном этапе все заработало. Дальше буду разбираться.